# Backing Up User home Folders in an Active Directory

Tags: backup, permissions, active-directory, windows-server-2012

Our Domain is currently Set up with a Server 2012 domain controller.

We have Home profiles enabled, which is annoying because it grants the User and only the user access to their files. We need to find a way to backup these files. I.e. grant admins access to these files too.

The backup we use is based on a scheduled task running Robocopy to bulk move files to another server. From there they get backed up to a tape.

I have already tried:

- running the scheduled task as "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"
- Granting Permissions to the root of the home folder

I am aware that I can manually take ownership of the folders, the fix the permissions from there, but I would prefer another solution (if it exists) as we have around 300 users in the domain.

Comment: What is wrong with granting your admin group full NTFS permissions?

Comment: `which is annoying because it grants the User` - There are group policies that will remove this behaviour.  But using them won't change the ACLs after the fact.  So you could apply the policies, then mass reset the permissions and include a backup group.

Comment: @Zoredache Care to elaborate which GPs would do this? I have absolutely no clue...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a user account (or add an existing user account) and add it to the `Backup Operators` group and run your task as that user.

Comment: Since the OP is using robocopy, they should also be passing the command line option to run robocopy in Backup Mode.  Either `/b`, or `/zb`.

Comment: @Zoredache Thanks, i'll give it a try tonight when the backups run!